# Django 3.0 - View a PDF in the browser

Tags: html, django, pdf, view

I simply want to click a link and view, in the browser, a PDF that I have uploaded to my Django project. To be sure in the Django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/outputting-pdf/) about how to create reports is not at all what I'm looking to do. I don't need to generate a PDF, I already have the ones I need. (This comes up a LOT in other answers.)

No luck with: [Render HTML to PDF in Django site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377446/render-html-to-pdf-in-django-site) (No surprise, it's 11 years)

Or: [Django - JS : How to display the first PDF page as cover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480677/django-js-how-to-display-the-first-pdf-page-as-cover) (somewhat surprised this is not the only time that a suggestion containing pdf.js occurs, I simply get an empty white square on me page with no further errors).

I have as well attempted embedding the PDF in a template with no luck.
([Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html))
(Tried  `<embed>` and `<iframe>`, and as you see in the link pdf.js once more. No go.)

How, generally, would one accomplish this specifically in Django 3.x?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. I'm not sure if you're talking about user uploaded files, or files that are static-files.

#### Approach 1

Just link to the relevant file from a template.
For user-uploaded files

```
{% load static %}
<a href="{% get_media_prefix %}name_of_pdf.pdf">Click Me</a>
```

For static files

```
{% load static %}
<a href="{% static 'name_of_pdf.pdf' %}">Click Me</a>
```

#### Approach

If you are trying to return the file from a view

```
from django.http import FileResponse


def load_file(request):
    file = ... # get file somehow
    return FileResponse(file)
```

See [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) for futher details. If the file is from your static folder, you could just use pythons `open` to read it. It depends on how you are serving your static files.

If this pdf is a user-uploaded file, attached to a model, you can access it via the appropriate field.

Comment: It took me until now to think to check on a Chrome, with which it works fine. Any idea as to why that would not work with Firefox?
Edit: There happens to be a setting for this.
And thank you.

Comment: What happens on Firefox? In what way does it not work?

Comment: In Firefox, the PDF was attempting to download and open. Just to be sure, this was fixed with a setting in the browser.